How can I see how much dividends I received over the past x days on the Interactive Brokers website?
How can I see how much dividends I received over the past x days on the Interactive Brokers website? It is easy to see this information on the Fidelity, Schwab, Boa, etc. websites, but I don't see it on the Interactive Brokers website.

One can go to statements and create a custom statement showing dividends:






